# C dll call from VBA : strange behavior

Tags: c, vba, dll

I write a C dll compiled in 64 bits with the following function:

in the .h :

```
_FF_EXPORT double __stdcall add(double a, double b);
```

in the .c :

```
double __stdcall add(double a, double b)
{
   return a+b;
}
```

Then I call it from VBA (also in 64 bits):

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function add Lib "sample.dll" (ByVal a As Double, ByVal b As Double) As Double

Public Sub addExcel()
On Error GoTo Err
    Dim a As Double
    Dim b As Double
    Dim res as Double

    a = 1
    b = 2
    res = add(a, b)
Err:
End Sub
```

When I debug in VisualStudio my dll, I see in the watch that
**a = 0.** and b = 2.

So it looks like 'a' doesn't get the proper value.
If instead of double I work with int (in both vba and dll), I get the correct values.
In fact, depending on the type of variables i work with and their number, sometimes I get what I want, sometimes a 0.

Is it possibly related to the fact that I'm working on 64 bits ?
Any other idea ?